# How to sort a collection that uses Guava Range values as keys?

Tags: java, sorting, guava

I have the following map, with `Range<Integer>` being the key:

```
| Range<Integer> | Set<Range<BigDecimal>>
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1..100         | [0.01..1.00], [2.01..15.00], [1.01..2.00]
------------------------------------------------------------
| 151..250       | [0.01..1.00], [2.01..15.00], [1.01..2.00]
------------------------------------------------------------
| 101..150       | [1.01..7.00], [0.01..1.00]
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also have the following comparator implementation:

```
public class RangeComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<Range<T>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Range<T> first, Range<T> second) {
        int comparatorResult = first.lowerEndpoint().compareTo(second.lowerEndpoint());
        return comparatorResult == 0 ? first.upperEndpoint().compareTo(second.upperEndpoint()) : comparatorResult;
    }
}
```

I'd like to sort the values in the map using this comparator, and then sort the map itself, thus get the following result:

```
| Range<Integer> | Set<Range<BigDecimal>>
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1..100         | [0.01..1.00], [1.01..2.00], [2.01..15.00]
------------------------------------------------------------
| 101..150       | [0.01..1.00], [1.01..7.00]
------------------------------------------------------------
| 151..250       | [0.01..1.00], [1.01..2.00], [2.01..15.00]
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The Guava Range class is final, and doesn't implement Comparable.

Can I sort this without implementing sorting by hand? If so, how?

Comment: `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` have constructors which takes an explicit `Comparator`. What stops you using this?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use TreeMap or TreeSet?

Comment: @AndyTurner Your answer was correct, please post it again. An unrelated TreeSet supplier that used the default constructor threw a ClassCastException, and I attributed that to the map sorting I tried to do. The custom comparator works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the constructors of [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)) and [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)) which take a `Comparator` as a parameter, e.g.

> ```
> public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)
> ```
>
> Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator.

Note that there is no restriction that the keys of the `TreeMap` or entries of the `TreeSet` need to implement `Comparable`.